# Pandas date index: select the first element of each month

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with dates as indices. For example:

```
            B group
index                  
2018-08-19     True
2018-08-20     True
2018-09-15     False
2018-09-15     False
2019-04-28     True
2019-06-01     False
2019-06-08     True
```

I want to select just the first element of each available month. For example in this DF I want to select these:

```
            B group
index                  
2018-08-19     True
2018-09-15     False
2019-04-28     True
2019-06-01     False
```

I have no idea how to do that. so I'm here to ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert `DatetimeIndex` to month periods by [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) and then filter by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with inverted mask and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df.index.to_period('m').duplicated()]
print (df)
            B group
2018-08-19     True
2018-09-15    False
2019-04-28     True
2019-06-01    False
```